# Erro do javaScript ao Abrir vsCode e Atom

Tags: atom, visual-studio-code

Toda vez que tento abrir o atom e o vsCode aparece essa mensagem:

> a javascript error ocurred in the main process

Image de erro no Atom:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no VSCode:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já apaguei do meu pc e baixei de novo, mas continua dando o mesmo problema, como posso resolve-lo?

Comment: Coloque também a mensagem de erro que aparece no VSCode

Comment: Pronto Coloquei, a mensagem de erro para os dois é mesma

Comment: Eu começaria por reinstalar os 2 confirmando que não fica nada em `User/AppData/Local` e `User/`  referente aos mesmos (em windows)

Comment: Eu reinstalo ele mas agora em caminho diferente do padrão?

Comment: Parece-me um bom teste. Do que eu pesquisei rapidamente no Google dessa mensagem de erro, a maior parte das resoluções passaram por reinstalar apenas. [Exemplo](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13327)